# Selenium click a button which is behind an div with higher z-index

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, z-index

I have a div which is defined as below:

```
<div class="Le8nfe" aria-hidden="true">
    <svg xmlns="https://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1440 810" 
       preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice" 
       aria-hidden="true" height="100%" width="100%">
         <!-- SOme path definition providing different background format -->
    </svg>
</div>
```

The above div has the following CSS definition for its class:

```
.Le8nfe {
  background: #fff;
  bottom: 0;
  direction: ltr;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

This is creating a background with a pattern. Then I have a button which is there in one of the `div` which is a sibling to the above `div` as shown below:

```
<div role="button" class="U26fgb O0WRkf zZhnYe C0oVfc sDzdve qxailb" 
    aria-disabled="false" tabindex="0">
    <div class="Vwe4Vb MbhUzd" jsname="ksKsZd"></div>
    <div class="ZFr60d CeoRYc"></div>
    <content class="CwaK9">
      <span class="RveJvd snByac">Yes</span>
    </content>
</div>
```

The problem I am facing is that using Selenium I am not able to click on the button. It says that the element is not visible.

Any idea on how to click on such elements which are shadowed by another div with higher z-index

Comment: You can use JavaScriptExecutor interface.

Comment: I have got this error when the element needed to be scrolled into view